# Linux sockets: Is there a way to only receive packets from a specific ring?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

My network server, for example, has

```
$ sudo ethtool -n if1
48 RX rings available
```

48 RX-rings. Is it possible to only receive packets from a socket which arrived on RX-ring 0, for example?
In case of multiple multicast-streams it is possible to steer packets on a specific ring:

```
sudo ethtool -N if1 flow-type udp4 action 0
```

48 processes listening on 48 different RX-Queues, processing 48 multicast-streams at the same time would be a drastic performance increase in comparison to processing packets from all RX-rings with a single process.